# Flex Builder, debugging - auto log console output

Tags: debugging, logging, console, flexbuilder

Can I make Flex Builder store all the output in the console window to a log file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Run/ Debug configuration, select the 'Common' tab.

On this page you'll find a check box that allows you to send output to a file